# How to Fix Terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm stuck. Ubuntu 11.10 was working fine. I tried to create a desktop icon that I could click and run a Terminal command. (not launch a program, just run a command to set something). I don't know what I did, but now I can't get Terminal to run at all. I can't click on Terminal in the Launchbar or use alt-F2. If I try, I see a VERY quick box open and close. If I switch to another user, Terminal does open and work fine? I can't even get it to open gconfig or x-term or x-term manager? Does anyone know how to reset Terminal without being able to get into Terminal? I tried going into synaptic and removing Terminal, and then re-installing it, but it didn't change the behavior at all, it still won't open.

Comment: What command was in your desktop icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. In the virtual terminal, give your username and password to login.
3. Execute these commands:

   ```
    rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal
    gconftools --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal
   ```

And see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Install another terminal emulator, and try to run gnome-terminal, see what kind of error messages you get, if any.

You can also use ctrl-alt-f1 to switch to terminal mode, but starting X programs from there might be tricky.