# How can i fix my Terminal login issue?

Tags: command-line, gnome, login, gnome-terminal

I've done a stupid mistake on Terminal preferences and now when i open it, it closes.

I managed to add a log-in set up when i access Terminal so it will ask me for sudo password. But i accidentally added a null "%00" character on the log-in command, and now every time i open the Terminal, it closes instantly.

I uninstalled gnome-terminal, and removed all possible temporary files, deleted ~/.gconf/gnome-terminal - and deleted all "gnome-terminal" existing files and folders. Then i reinstalled "gnome-terminal" via UXTerm, but still when i open it, it closes due to that log-in command i added. Now i don't know what to do to fix this problem. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: What do you mean by *"add a log-in set up"*? What **exactly** did you do?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm thinking he means an auto-execute command

Comment: You can access Terminal preferences and on "Command" set-up a log-in command, like "sudo -i".  But when i was adding the command i added "null" because of a bug with my keyboard, and saved it. When i did that, is that the issue started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've finally found my fix for this.

It's a terminal user issue where i ran a command for log in with terminal.

I fixed it with this command: `gnome-terminal -x /bin/bash`

Then fixed the log-in command. That's how i fixed the issue.

Anyways, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this a go:

1. Switch to TTY1 via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>`
2. Log in to your user
3. Run these commands:

   `rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal
   gconftools --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal`

Hopefully this will take care of it! [Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/185077/136381)

Comment: When i executed the first command i got a "No such file or directory" error, even after installed gnome-terminal and executed it. When executed the second command nothing appeared. When i ran gnome-terminal via UXTerm i got a theme parsing error: No such file or directory.

And yeah, it's an user log-in issue.

Comment: @AlejandroHabboGameAcevedo Hmm...dunno then :( I'll look around a bit more.

Comment: @AlejandroHabboGameAcevedo Can you post the output of `cat ~/.profile`?

Comment: I don't have a .profile folder

Comment: @AlejandroHabboGameAcevedo I know, it's not a folder, it's a file. Glad you solved it though :)